# how can I copy files to the file system of android?

Tags: android, filesystems

How can I copy files to the file system (place) in android? How can I access it?

Comment: is this a programming question or a user question? are you copying *from* your computer? your android device? to the SD card? is your SD card mounted, if connected to the computer?

Comment: This is a programming question. All I need is the path.
I want to put some files so the user won't have any access to them. I think this is the best way to do it

Comment: I thought I understood your question until I read your comment.  Are you trying to write files to the file system (ie in your code running inside Dalvik) or are you trying to deploy them (via a physical connection to a host machine)?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. I don't know what is Dalvik mean.
I want to write files to the file system (not the sdcard) using code.
By file system I mean the place where there are the hard files that if you delete them nothing will work and you even can't see them.
I need a way to make files not accessible to the user. Maybe you know a better way to do it?

Comment: Check out my answer.  Dalvik is the virtual machine that executes your code; it is comparable to the Java virtual machine.  Check out this wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_virtual_machine

Answer (score 11):

copy files from android to local

```
adb pull /data/data/com.example.sample ./sample/
```

copy file to android from local

```
adb push ./sample/ /sdcard/sample/
```

Comment: +1 You can also do this from the DDMS application if you prefer to click things, but that's just a GUI implementation of these commands.

Comment: I don't want to copy to the sdcard...I want to copy to the file system directory

Comment: i don't think you write to the android file system directory directly. its only possible programmatically from the application that you are working on. Each application is given a protected space inside the /data/data/myApp , so this way one application cannot write to another apps folder. Well i'm a little out of touch with android development at the moment so i may be wrong.

Comment: I want to do it programmatically. Do you know how to do it? 
How can I get the app folder path?

Comment: ok.. there's Context.openFileOutput() which will give you a FileOutputStream to write on. 

here's what you may need to explore: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but here's another interpretation of your question:

You can place files in the `assets` folder in the project on your development machine.  They will be bundled into the apk file and then access them through the `AssetManager` class.  Something like this from within a Service or Activity class:

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("filename");
```

This will allow you to read the contents of those files.  I don't believe you can write to them though.  There are other options for if you need to read and write files in your application's storage sandbox.  This is done by calling `openFileOutput()`.  I should note though that the user can always access the files on the device through ddms but other applications won't be able to access files stored in your application's storage sandbox.

**Edit** Based on your comment, you probably want to use

```
OutputStream out = openFileOutput("outfile");
```

to write to a file from your code.  This code must be called from within an `Activity` or `Service` (something that extends `Context`). This file will be stored on the phone's file system and not on the sdcard.  These files will not be accessible to the average user.  If users know how to enable usb debugging then they will be able to access them and there is really no way around this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

That will give you `/sdcard` if your device has an sdcard, or something different in other cases. For example the Archos.

Comment: I know this...but this is not what I asked.

Answer (score 1):

I took some time to research about android's system files earlier, but almost always with android x86, i found out that the /system folder inside android is read-only,

it is an image with format is SFS format, this is read-only image format of linux so i don't think you can copy some thing inside this folder. I not sure about rooted android. Hope it will help  you.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably hide your file in the sdcard by prefixing it with a dot (ex: .myfile)

Comment: In this case, the user can attach the device to the computer and then see the files. Am I right?

Comment: If he browse the sdcard from a windows box yes. But if you really don't want the user to mess with your file, use assets or raw resource. The only drawback is that it's readonly.

Maybe you can use a database instead ?