# "The application .... has stopped unexceptedly" Reading Files

Tags: android, file

I have an xml in /data//files/file.xml and another txt file in same location. I am not able to read those files. It throws me error "The application <...> has stopped unexceptedly" with "Force Close" button and the application quits.

Can anyone help me know the cause of it ? I am really stuck up.

Comment: Launching your application in the Emulator, from Eclipse, you should take a look at the LogCat : when an exception occurs, a stacktrace will be displayed there -- to display LogCat : `Window > Show View > Other... > Android > LogCat`

Comment: Yes, I got "File not found". As I said file is stored at data/<pckg>/files folder. I access it directly as File f = new File(file.xml). While storing if we just give filename, it is stored here, then while retrieving, how do we retrieve it ? Any path or so to give ?

Comment: How did you put the file there? How did you verify that the file actually is there?

Comment: @Mike, I added the file through DDMS. Will I be able to store the file similarly during instalaltion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Friends,

I found a solution and now could read the file stored in files folder.
Thanks a lot for your help and support.

Answer (score 1):

You cant access Ur data file like that.

follow these steps

1. Create a folder in res folder with name as raw . and save your XML file in raw folder.
2. then use

   ```
     InputStream inp = Context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.datafile);
   ```

u will get InputStream reference. where u can proceed further with it as u need.

Comment: Saving file like this will be included in the project when I package it, I mean copy to device or install on device ?

Comment: if u r trying to copy the file to FileSystem of android , if im not wrong check this.. link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668282/how-can-i-copy-files-to-the-file-system-of-android. sorry if im not helped u in this.

Comment: @ user593424, No. What I meant was, like in our Windows app, if we add file to the project itself, it gets added wherever we isntall our app. Same way, if I add in /res, the file will also be availalbe wherever I install/download the app. Basically, it will stay with the project always like our other resources, components stay ??? I hope I have made my query more clearer.